# How can I change the background-image in Wordpress divi theme?

Tags: wordpress

Since I cleared css cache with the plugin WpRocket in Wordpress, some pages of my website (www.florian-drums.com) show the wrong background-image. When I log into the Wordpress Dashboard in click visit website, all is correct. But when I logout and visit my Website the following pages display a wrong background-image (the one with the drums - there should be no background-image at all):

```
  https://www.florian-drums.com/mein-unterrichtskonzept/
  https://www.florian-drums.com/preise/
  https://www.florian-drums.com/media/
```

When I log into the dashboard and visit some of the pages and enable divi-builder and click save and logout, the website is showed correctly again. But after a few clicks, suddenly the background-image is displayed again. I tested this on my Iphone, Ipad and Macbook...still the same problem. Please help!

Comment: This is a cache issue with Divi. Go to Divi > Theme Options > Builder. On the advanced tab, if the Static CSS File Generation is enabled, click the Clear button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I click the Clear button it works, but after a few clicks through the menu the problem still appears.... Any Ideas??

Comment: This is definitely a cache issue. Check in a private browser window.

Comment: Same Issue......

Comment: I also tried it on different devices... still the same problem

Comment: Are you using a CDN or other caching besides WP Rocket and Divi?